# Consume build outputs from other build definitions

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I have a product A that reference dlls from other internal sub-products (B and C) of the same company, all being build in the same Build Controller but, obviously, using its own build definition.

Each product have its independent release life-cycle, however, A needs to be build always with the latest version available of B and C.

Is there a way we can setup TFS-Online to get the outputs from the output of builds of B and C as sources for the build of A (maybe using the Drop location)?

I wanted to implement something like here in [Subsystem branching](http://geekswithblogs.net/terje/archive/2008/11/02/article-on-subsystem-branching.aspx), but I get myself blocked due to VS Team Services does not allow `TF.exe` to checkin the outputs in a Common folder because lack of credentials (and when passing ones, it gets stuck on the UI).

How do you deal with these kind of mid-complex internal-dependencies?

Comment: Package B and C as nuget packages and publish them to a repository (this can be a file share)

Comment: Are you using Build vNext or XAML build?

Comment: @Cece i'm using XAML build

Comment: @JamesReed, great idea, unfortunately this company is not using nuget yet. I would like to know if there is a way we can deal with this by using only the Source Control in order to allow any devs to get the full code running by giving access only to the source control.

Comment: @wOOdy..., seems you take to use Solution 3 in this blog (http://geekswithblogs.net/terje/archive/2008/11/02/article-on-subsystem-branching.aspx). Any further details about the issues you got when using TF checkin command? You can use:" tf checkin  /collection:https://vsoaccount.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection /shelveset:shelvesetname "

Answer (score -1):

Open the product A in Solution Explorer, right click Reference to Add Reference, select Project-Solution, and add product B and product C. In this way, when you build product A, it will automatically get outputs of product B and product C. Make sure in Solution Explorer, product A works as expect (Using outputs of product B and product C).

Then in Build Definitaion, add all products (B,C,A) in the Projects to Build, make products B,C are in front of product A, so that Products B,C will build first(it's necessary).

Comment: This implies building B and C every time A needs to be built. But that is not the idea. We want to reference the latest officially released DLLs for B and C and not build B and C.